# SQLite DateTime <Unable to Read Data> in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sqlite, datetime

Some of my DateTime values have been entered in the format YYYY-M-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS (please note single month i.e. '2013-1-03 09:10:00.000' instead of the correct ISO-8601 '2013-01-03 09:10:00.000'

I'm using SYSTEM.DATA.SQLite to read the data from the database in Visual Studio 2010 and for those records where the datetime has been entered as a single digit month I get  in the designer and *blank* ('') during runtime.

Is there any way I can read this data in VS2010 and correct the format?

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry it appears HTML formating changed the text of my questions slightly. What I meant to say above was... "...where the datetime has been entered as a single digit month I get <Unable to read data> in the designer and blank ('') during runtime."

Answer (score 0):

Use a query like this:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET MyDate = substr(MyDate, 1, 5) || '0' || substr(MyDate, 6)
WHERE MyDate LIKE '____-_-%'
```